# Providing Spanned variable to ellipsized TextView results in ellipsize for single line too, how to prevent this?

Tags: android, textview

I have a recycler view list and each list item has a textview which is populated from network response and response could be either normal text or most often html, below is the code.

```
Spanned htmlAsSpanned = Html.fromHtml(item.getDescription().trim());
holder.content.setText(htmlAsSpanned);
```

Note that I have set ellipsize as true and maxlines as 1 for this text View "content". Below is a possible input text in text view

```
<p>some text </p>
```

When there is multiple lines of text ellipsizing is happening which is expected.
However, when the input has single line also ellipsize is applied!, so the above line will come like

```
some text ...
```

What could I do to prevent single line html input from getting ellipsized?

Note: This is happening only when I convert to spanned and pass html text.Without conversion of the content, it will ellipsize only if it is more than one line which is perfectly fine.

Comment: So why do you convert to spanned?

Comment: Html.fromHTML method gives me spanned variable as return value (this method I need to use for converting html content I may receive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution that worked for me...

```
  Spanned htmlDescription = Html.fromHtml(item.getDescription());
  String descriptionWithOutExtraSpace = new String(htmlDescription.toString()).trim();
  holder.content.setText(htmlDescription.subSequence(0, descriptionWithOutExtraSpace.length()));
```